# Can't access app deployed to IBM Bluemix Strong-pm container

Tags: ibm-cloud, strongloop

I am trying to deploy an app to a default IBM Strong-pm container but can't access the running app on <--public-ip-->:3001 even though everything seems to be in order.

I have a local container running from the exact same image and everything works fine. The only thing I can think of that could be causing the problem is the port mappings.

This is the configuration from my local docker that works:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      NAMES
c582675b270a        registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/ibm-node-strong-pm   "/usr/local/bin/sl-pm"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:32779->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32778->3001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32777->3002/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32776->3003/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32775->3004/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32774->3005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32773->3006/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32772->3007/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32771->3008/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32770->3009/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32769->3010/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->8701/tcp   dfect-test
```

The configuration on my Bluemix Container is the following:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                  COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS                                                                                            NAMES
db4d2ff4-479        registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/ibm-node-strong-pm:latest   ""                  About an hour ago   Running an hour ago    134.168.35.46:22->22/tcp, 134.168.35.46:3001-3004->3001-3004/tcp, 134.168.35.46:8701->8701/tcp   Test
```

I can deploy my app to the container and it seems to be running:

```
2015-11-16T21:25:45.962Z pid:2449 worker:78 INFO strong-agent v1.6.4 profiling app 'dfect-backend' pid '2449'
2015-11-16T21:25:45.964Z pid:2449 worker:78 INFO strong-agent[2449] started profiling agent
2015-11-16T21:25:47.399Z pid:2449 worker:78 Environment:  dev
2015-11-16T21:25:47.399Z pid:2449 worker:78 Running app in DEVELOPMENT MODE
2015-11-16T21:25:47.401Z pid:2449 worker:78 INFO strong-agent not profiling, agent metrics requires a valid license.
2015-11-16T21:25:47.401Z pid:2449 worker:78 Please contact sales@strongloop.com for assistance.
2015-11-16T21:25:47.408Z pid:2449 worker:78 Browse your REST API at http://0.0.0.0:3001/explorer
2015-11-16T21:25:47.408Z pid:2449 worker:78 Web server listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3001/
```

I just can't access it from the browser.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Okay, I managed to get the app running using slc ctl env-set <service> PORT=3000. I am not sure why this works as well as why this was not necessary on the local version. Any clarification would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

Containers has started whitelisting certain ports for exposure to the internet now for security purpose. This means that unless the port you have exposed is on the list, you won't be able to communicate on that port. If you want to open a new port for your container you should open a ticket on [https://support.ng.bluemix.net/gethelp](https://support.ng.bluemix.net/gethelp/)

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where can I find a list of the whitelisted ports?

Comment: There is not a list of the public whitelisted ports exposed by container. For security purpose It is not avaible. But when the client has an issue he can always open a ticket and ask if he can use that specific port.

Answer (score 0):

I also got no response from port 3001 of the container. I contacted with Bluemix Help and now the ports is open. I confirmed that I could access port 3001.